# Strange behaviour of Set and Part when given a sequence

Tags: functions, core-language

Consider this example:

```
lis1 = {a, b, c};
lis1[[2]] = Sequence[e, f];
lis1
(*{a, e, f, c}*)
lis1[[2]]
(*e*)
lis1[[2]] = Sequence[g, h];
lis1
(*{a, g, h, c}*)
```

It looks like position 2 in lis1 is still has head `Sequence`, yet no sign of `Sequence` in the full form of lis1.

Can any one explain why is this happening?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2009/Nov/msg00189.html).

Comment: @LeonidShifrin, lis1 = DeleteCases[lis1, Sequence, -1]; will completely solve the problem but I get confused how to explain this because Sequence is a head and as far as I know you can not completely delete head but replace head by another head.

Comment: Read more carefully the linked explanation. In `DeleteCases`, `Sequence` disappears in `lis1` as a result of evaluation.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin thanks a lot. I got it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this readily explained by looking at the own-values of the variable after the assignment is made.

```
v = {a, b, c}; v[[2]] = Sequence[e, f];
OwnValues @ v
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[v] :> {a, Sequence[e, f], c}}
> ```

It's rather like `Defer`, so it will behave like `{a, e, f, c}` under standard evaluation. But it can behave differently in non-standard evaluation. When this would be a problem, you can always do

```
v = v
```

> ```
> {HoldPattern[v] :> {a, e, f, c}}
> ```

to get variable bound to the fully evaluated form.

Comment: `Set` using non-standard evaluation wouldn't alone be enough to provide this behavior. The key here is that `Set` and `SetDelayed` (as well as `Rule` and `RuleDelayed`) are also `SequenceHold`.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin. You're right. I did not mean to imply the `Set` alone was the culprit. Bad wording on my part. I will try to fix it.

Comment: No worries, I didn't mean that comment as a critique, just as an additional piece of information.