# Deleting multiple elements from a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list with many elements `(189)` and I want to delete certain elements from it. I have a list of elements I want deleted from it:

```
{3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 13, 15, 16, 19, 22, 33, 35, 38, 39, 40, 47, 48, 49,
 50, 51, 52, 53, 63, 64, 78, 126, 143, 160, 167, 170, 173, 174, 179, 189}
```

And I want to end up with a list of `155` elements.

The Delete command seems to only work for one specified element.

My attempt is this(for a simpler list):

```
list = {1, 2, 3}
nonopt = {1, 3}
For[i = 1, i < 4, i++,
 If[MemberQ[nonopt, i], list[[i]] = 0]]
```

What I'm trying to do is make all elements I want deleted equal to zero and then find out how I can delete all zero elements, but I'm getting stuck here. For some reason, list ends up being equal to `{0,0,0}` despite `MemberQ[nonopt,2]` evaluating to false.

Comment: Use `If`, not 'if', and your code works.

Comment: See also [Complement on pre-sorted lists](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30429/complement-on-pre-sorted-lists)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Order preserving, deletes any instance(s) in list of element(s) in nonopt,
about 50X faster than using e.g. `DeleteCases`, and quite a bit faster than non order preserving complement:

```
DeleteDuplicates[Join[nonopt, list]][[Length@nonopt + 1 ;;]]
```

BTW - this is based on my interpretation of OP - it is unclear if the intent is a list of values or indices to be deleted... if it *is* indices, this should perform about as fast as possible:

```
Delete[list, Partition[nonopt, 1]]
```

Comment: Great! I tried the second code and it also worked for nested lists.

Answer (score 12):

```
list = {1, 4, 1, 2, 3, 5};
nonopt = {1, 3};
```

This gives a sorted output:

```
Complement[list, nonopt]
```

> ```
> {2, 4, 5}
> ```

To preserve the order, this is a simple method.

```
DeleteCases[list, Alternatives @@ nonopt]
```

> ```
> {4, 2, 5}
> ```

**Edit**

For `list` with lists, matching on the first element:

```
list = {{1, a}, {4, d}, {1, x}, {2, b}, {3, c}, {2, y}, {5, e}};
nonopt = {1, 3};

DeleteCases[list, {Alternatives @@ nonopt, __}]
```

> ```
> {{4, d}, {2, b}, {2, y}, {5, e}}
> ```

Comment: Thanks so much, the DeleteCases method does exactly what I was asking. I noticed it doesn't work if I have a list of lists. so if list is {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}} and nonopt is {1,3}, I just get the same list back. why is that?

Comment: The pattern match on `DeleteCases` needs to match the element forms in `list`.  I have added an example for a list of lists.

Answer (score 6):

```
l = Range@189;
r = {3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 13, 15, 16, 19, 22, 33, 35, 38, 39, 40, 47, 48, 
    49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 63, 64, 78, 126, 143, 160, 167, 170, 173, 174, 179, 189};
d = Delete[l, List /@ r]
Length@d
(* 155 *)
```

Comment: This is deleting items at positions in `r`, rather than matching items.  (The OP uses `MemberQ` in his code, and seems to be mistaking usage of `Delete`, which is deletes by position.)

Comment: He does `MemberQ` on the loop index..

Answer (score 3):

```
l = Range@189;
 r = {3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 13, 15, 16, 19, 22, 33, 35, 38, 39,
   40, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 63, 64, 78, 126, 143, 160, 167, 
  170, 173, 174, 179, 189};
l[[r]] = Sequence[];
l = l;
Length[l]
(*155*)
```

Comment: Interesting approach. There is no reason for the `l=l;` is there?

Comment: @george2079 check this `OwnValues[l]`  before and after `l=l`. Check this also http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59457/strange-behaviour-of-set-and-part-when-given-a-sequence